# How to access an autowired Controller like an Service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a controller `ContactController` that is registered as an service.

```
  CoreBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../Controller/'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

When I try to access the ContactController, I get the following error message:

> Service "ContactBundle\Controller\ContactController" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\AppController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "session" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.

How can I access this service?

Answer (score 2):

From the information you provide is assume you try to do something like:

```
$controller = $this->get(MyController:class);
```

Since Symfony 4 this way of getting services is not recommended anymore and the container got limited to the few services you can see in your error message.

The recommended way is to use dependency injection to get your services e.g.:

```
__construct(MyController $myController){

}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service

But it's also not recommended to use Controllers as Services. This should only be done in specific situations and when you know what you are doing.